# Python variables passing

Tags: python, variables, optimization, procedure

I want to create a set_range procedures whose goal is to define biggest and smallest number from group of 3. Final step would be minus operation.

I wrote the first two parts but final part is not working. The issue seems to be with passing the variables from one to another...

```
#biggest number
def biggest(a, y, z):
    Max = a
    if y > Max:
        Max = y    
    if z > Max:
        Max = z
        if y > z:
            Max = y
    return Max
#print biggest(10, 4, 7) TEST ONLY

#smallest number
def smallest(a, y, z):
    Small = a
    if y < Small:
        Small = y    
    if z < Small:
        Small = z
        if y < z:
            Small = y
    return Small
#print smallest (10, 4, 7) TEST ONLY

#final part of the code, Max - Small operation
def set_range():
  m = Max
  s = Small

print set_range
```

Comment: create a global variable.

Comment: you can also resolve this using a class and making them public methods so you can access constructor variables and local variables from each method.

Comment: Just to be clear: You're aware that `max` and `min` already handle this, right? If it's a class assignment, do what you need to do, but otherwise, the answer is `return max(a, y, z)` and `return min(a, y, z)`.

Comment: You need to actually call `biggest` and `smallest` functions inside `set_range`. `set_range` will also need to accept the three numbers to be compared.

Comment: @eddwinpaz: What persistent state is needed to compute min and max? Forcing classes on something is pointless when there is no state to maintain, nor behaviors of said state.

Comment: @eddwinpaz neither of those approaches is necessary, really. You can just use normal functions and pass parameters between them. Indeed, I think suggesting using global variables is bad advice. As for your class suggesting, that is one approach, albeit overkill in this case, IMO, but regardless python doesn't have access modifiers so there are no "public" and "private" methods

Comment: @ShadowRanger - I'm starting my programming advanture and for now I follow the tutorial guidelines ;) but yes - I am aware of max/min function. The issue I have is to understand the logic behind variables passing from one procedure to another. I improved the code with your ideas.

Comment: I modified the code with calling biggest and smallest functions inside set_range and works good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can access all variables from all methods within your code this means, share numbers from biggest() and smallest()

```
 class getOperationMax(a,y,z):

      def __init__(self,a,y,z):
        self.y = y
        self.a = y
        self.z = y
        self.Max = 0
        self.Small = 0

      #biggest number
      def biggest(self):
          self.Max = self.a
          if self.y > self.Max :
              self.Max = self.y
              self.max = self.y    
          if self.z > self.Max:
              self.Max = self.z
              if self.y > self.z:
                  self.Max = self.y

          return self.Max
      #print biggest(10, 4, 7) TEST ONLY

      #smallest number
      def smallest(self):
          self.Small = self.a
          if self.y < self.Small:
              self.Small = self.y    
          if self.z < self.Small:
              self.Small = self.z
              if self.y < self.z:
                  self.Small = self.y
          return self.Small
      #print smallest (10, 4, 7) TEST ONLY

    operation = getOperationMax(5,6,7)
    print operation.biggest()
    print operation.smallest()
```